# Floating point because of diodes in circuit design

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, circuit-design

I wonder that this  part of[image] the circuit which I design , can there be floating point in right  sides of D2 and D1  due to  the voltages changing from -12V to +12 V on the left sides of diodes.

Comment: If something external forces these nets to a certain voltage, how could they possibly be floating?

Comment: When you say "floating point" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: But applied voltage is on the left side of the diode.When voltage is +12 V   what is the voltage on the right side of the diode ? Do resistor which goes to ground prevent floating point?

Comment: It sort of depends on your definition of floating. Above around -0.7V on the left side of the diodes, (in this case) the right side of the diodes is not driven by anything other than the stuff on the right of R7 and R8. Except perhaps capacitively

Comment: Right side of the diode can take any value independent of the left side @EugeneSh.

Comment: I say the same thing there is no stuff on the right side.@Trevor

Comment: Are you simply asking if a diode can be considered as an open-circuit when back-biased?

Comment: I want this circuit to work only when  -12 V applied and gives nothing as output of the op amp when +12 is applied

Comment: SInce we have no idea what it is or what it is supposed to do.. how can we answer that?

Comment: I ask a simple question İf  I apply +12 to the left side  , how can I make it possible for the right side voltage to be 0V.

Comment: Should I connect right side directly to ground with resistor?

Comment: Sigh.. what is U3.. what are voltages a and b, what is U3 connected to.... how zero do you need zero... don't say things are simple.. they never are.

Comment: @distortion, `I ask a simple question İf I apply +12 to the left side , how can I make it possible for the right side voltage to be 0V.`  you did not ask that at all. your question is "distorted" ... lol .... re-read your question  .... edit your question, if that is what you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the D2 cathode is at +12 V (or anything above -0.5 V), the anode will be at GND through 4 K of resistance.  When the D1 cathode is at +12 V (or anything above -0.5 V), the anode will be at GND through 3 K of resistance.

Note - the transition voltage mentioned above (-0.5 V) is a generic example, and will vary with the diode type.  Less for Schottkey, more for a power rectifier, etc.  Also, diode leakage current might impress a small voltage across the resistances, moving the anode away from GND by a few mV.